# How to phrase this question in proper English?

Tags: sentence-construction

> Cutter send his guards to kill Aramaki. So Guards rain(rain means
>   firing more bullets) their bullets on Aramaki's car. But Aramaki step
>   out of the car alive & kill those guards with his gun. How Aramaki still alive with so many bullets fired on him?

Note: Cutter not present at the location of firing takes place, he is somewhere & ordered his guards to kill him & also I used the word **guards** here, There are not actually guards & but they work under Cutter's command.

I want to phrase this question in proper English.

Comment: *How is Aramaki still alive, with so many bullets fired at him?*

Comment: @StoneyB I want to mention **Cutter guards** also in my question, they are **main roles** in my question, I don't want to neglect them.

Comment: *How is Aramaki stil alive after Cutter's guards fired so many bullets at him?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Cutter **sent** his guards to kill Aramaki. So **the** guards **rained** their bullets on Aramaki's car. But Aramaki **steps** out of the car alive and **kills** those guards with his gun. How **is** Aramaki still alive with so many bullets fired **at** him?

There are several problems with your original text, which I've corrected above.

1. It is more normal to use the past tense when describing something that has already occurred: Cutter *sent,* the guards *rained.*
2. The number of the subject and the verb must agree: Aramaki *steps* and *kills.*
3. To ask a question, you generally invert the subject/verb: *Aramaki is alive,* but *How is Aramaki alive?*
4. There's no need to capitalize guards.